# How to increase headphone jack volume output on a Bluetooth speaker

Tags: speakers

We have a rechargeable Bluetooth speaker with a 3.5 mm headphone jack. We often connect pillow speakers to that headphone jack to help manage tinnitus at night. The challenge is that the pillow speakers are not amplified - they are simple 4 ohm, 2 watt speakers. What electronic modifications could be made to the Bluetooth speaker's electronics to increase the output to the connected pillow speakers so that the dB coming from the speakers is louder? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A small amplifier would be probably easiest.